# Simple query by _id with mongoose and node.js not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, objectid

objective:

**Find one document from mongodb by its _id.**

Environment:

**JavaScript, Node.js, Mongoose**

So i have this code... (here a portion of an "Post" Schema)

```
PostSchema.statics = {
   findById: function (id, cb) {
       this.findOne({ _id : { $eq: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id) } }).exec(cb);
   }
}
```

And then this other code calling this method:

```
var Post = mongoose.model('Post');
Post.findById('54986a8b43db661a0ec827e4', function(result){
     console.log(result);
});
```

I get the error: Can't use $eq with ObjectId

I tried the query **db.posts.find({_id: {$eq: ObjectId('54986a8b43db661a0ec827e4')}});** directly in mongodb engine and it works, but not in mongoose...

So i don't know what to do for querying just by an id!

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because [`$eq`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/#exp._S_eq) is an aggregation operator.  Just use a direct comparison instead:

```
PostSchema.statics = {
   findById: function (id, cb) {
       this.findOne({ _id : id }).exec(cb);
   }
}
```

You don't need to make an ObjectId out of `id` as Mongoose will do that casting for you.

But you don't even need to create this method yourself as the built-in [`findById`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById) method does the same thing.

Comment: that returns null ... :(

Comment: @Rimbuaj The first parameter to the callback is the error parameter, the second parameter is the found doc. So the `null` is just indicating that there wasn't an error.